# What are good strategies for determining who should be made a chat room owner?

Tags: discussion, chat

What are good strategies for determining who should be made a chat room owner?

For example, recently there was some discussion over making another member a room owner. I declined citing several reasons.

I suggested that the requestor may want to earn a few more rep for the room topic before making him or her a room owner.

I feel that tags on a site are an important bit of recognition and that it's fair that we encourage people to take room ownership when they have value to contribute to the community, and not just because they want the ability to boot people from the room. There's not exactly a lot of benefit to being a room owner on a less active room anyways.

What are your suggested guidelines for determining who should be made a chat room owner?

Comment: FWIW only mods can kick anyway

Comment: Activity.  Maturity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kinda got automatically made a chat room owner. It ended up working ok - though I usually do agree that "Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government".

TLDR: ROship's a matter of trust.

I think the primary goal of bestowing a room ownership, is responsibility. RO's are the  <strike>responsible adults</strike>  teenage babysitters of chat. They have just enough powers to maintain *some* semblance or order, but really do need to call in an adult if there's a major issue, like a troll infestation or the oven catching fire cause little billy stuck his sister's doll in it and set it to over 9000. Being able to have *some* influence and not needing to use negative reinforcement to get people to behave is always a bonus

The *process* is less important - at some point I set up a group of trusted users as Room Owners on root access simply because I realised mods couldn't cover chat all the time, and they could deal with the worst of it before it got, well even worse. They hardly ever boot anyone, and a good chunk of them are potential moderator material (one of the later batch became a mod, and some of the others are pretty handy on meta).

I went for "enough" and spread them out over a few timezones for good coverage. 3-4 seems like a good number for a busy room. I suppose where you don't have a mod or two propping up the bar, existing trusted ROs can probably suggest good candidates.

Contrariwise, some folks have been pretty terrible room owners - I've seen people kicked cause they said something that was ill adviced on a test room, which was moved to a primary room, where it was flagged. We've also had rooms where self regulation's been less than stellar and ROs working to help things stay on keel would have been nice. Once again - its a matter of using those abilities judiciously.

Comment: Excellent comments! Thanks JG!